# in the page i have for loop function? In The for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){ Size Query retrieve only one row from mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

in the page i have for loop function? In The `for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){` `Size Query` retrieve only one `row` from mysql database and `for loop repeat that size row again and again` when ever `new product is entered?`

**Page Function**

```
    <?php
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Item Code</font></td><td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Product Name</font></td>
<td align="center"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Product Image</font></td>
<td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Price</font></td>
<td><div><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Size</font></div></td>
<td><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:14px; color:#000;">Options</font></td></tr>';

 $max=count($_SESSION['cart'] );
 for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){
 $id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
 $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
 $product=get_product_name($id);
 $image=get_product_image($id);
 $ids=get_id($id);
 $itemcode=get_itemcode($id);
 $size=get_size($id);
 if($q==0) continue;

 ?>
 </table>


 <diiv style="float:left; margin-left:42px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
 <?php echo $itemcode; ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="itemcode[]" value="<?php echo $itemcode?>" /></font></div><br />

 <div style="float: left;margin-left: 122px; margin-top: -14px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
 <?php echo $product?>
 <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $product?>" /></font></div><br />


<div style="float: left;margin-left: 387px;margin-top: -24px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<img name="image" id="image" src="admin/uploads/small0_<?php echo $image?>" width="150" height="150">
<input type="hidden" name="image[]" id="image"  value="<?php echo $image?>"  /> </font></div><br />

<div style="float: left;margin-left: 548px;margin-top: -147px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php echo get_price($id) ?>
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="<?php echo get_price($id)?>" /></font></div><br />

<?php //foreach ($size as $sizes) { ?>
<div style="float: left;margin-left: 625px;margin-top: -149px;"><font style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px; color:#000;">
<?php echo $size; ?> 
</font><input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>" /></font></div><?php //}?><br />

<div style="float: left;margin-left:686px;margin-top: -150px;"><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $id?>)">
<input type="button" class="button5" value="Remove" /></a></div><br /> 
<hr style="width:800px" />  

<?php                   
}
?>

 <?php
 }
 else{
 echo "There are no items in your shopping cart!";
 }
 ?>
```

**Size Query**

```
function get_size($id){
$result=mysql_query("SELECT size FROM mywishlist order by id") or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
return $row['size'];
}}
```

**Mywishlist Table Screenshot**
[image: now see there are two sizes in the size column]

**Page Screenshot**
[image: page screenshot]

Comment: Yes, and? is there a problem?

Comment: @mark please tell me why for loop repeat single row again and again for every products

Comment: You have a `return` statement in a `while` loop. The `while` loop will only get executed at most 1 time.

Comment: @nickb any solution or example ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `get_size()` functions re-runs the query **EVERY** time you call the function, then you **IMMEDIATELY** return from the loop on the first row.

in short, you need to learn basic programming.

Comment: marc b can you tell me what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with the construction of your `qet_size()` function.

First off, your query is not built right based on what your objective is. Your function is

```
function get_size($id){
```

but you do not take `$id` into consideration. A proper query would be the following

```
SELECT size FROM mywishlist WHERE id = $id
```

Your problem is that you're grabbing **ALL** of the rows in the table and only ordering them by `id`. Then you loop through each one and **only** returns the size of the first row you hit. The query I provided will return you only one row which you can then return the value given.

**NOTICE**: MySQL_* has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO